# Docker FreeRadius setup

Tags: docker, dockerfile, freeradius

I'm trying to setup the docker configuration as described on: https://hub.docker.com/r/freeradius/freeradius-server

So I want to use my own local configuration files, first I created the folder /etc/raddb/, then created the file Dockerfile with this content:

```
FROM freeradius/freeradius-server:latest
COPY raddb/ /etc/raddb/
```

After that's being saved, I run the command: `sudo docker build -t "freeradius:latest" .`
The output:
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.188MB

```
Step 1/2 : FROM freeradius/freeradius-server:latest
 ---> a5c7e0829368
Step 2/2 : COPY raddb/ /etc/raddb/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 41b177ad8a07
Successfully built 41b177ad8a07
Successfully tagged freeradius:latest
```

There are no error or whatsoever, but when I check the folder with: `sudo ls /etc/raddb/`
It is totally empty. I'm new to docker and this is the first time I tried working with the Dockerfile, am I doing something wrong?

I did try setting the permissions on the folder to rwx but still the same.
Also tried running the command after I deleted the raddb folder and see if the Dockerfile would create it, itself, but that doesn't work, just gives an error that the file don't exist.

I was expecting a folder filled with the .conf files that are present if you download the image and unzip it.